# how do i get my android app which is connected to a realtime firebase database to create a toast on update in the realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my fireabase databse
[View Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUOs9.png)

All I want is to generate a toast or a notification in my android app saying what changes or which new entry was added under the faces or movements directory. I am trying to use the addValueEventListener() method but I cant get it to work. Below is the onCreate() method in my android app. I am trying to implement this by following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCDS6DaFSQ youtube tutorial. I have already connected my app to firebase. Also, I am trying to get this done by not using the firebase cloud function.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Firebase Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    myRef.child("App")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = snapshot.getChildren();

                    for (DataSnapshot child: children)
                    {
                        String value = child.getValue(String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
}
```

If this cannot be implemented by using the addValueEventListener() method, is there any other comparatively simpler alternative to this?

Here is my MainActivity.java(with two buttons)

````
package com.example.notification_test;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 001;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Firebase Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myRef.child("App").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = snapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child: children)
                {
                    String value = child.getValue(String.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void testFirebase(View view)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue("Hello");
    }

    public void displayNotification(View view)
    {
        createNotificationChannel();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sms);
        builder.setContentTitle("Simple Notification");
        builder.setContentText("This is a simple notification..");
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    }

    private void createNotificationChannel()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            CharSequence name = "Personal Notifications";
            String description = "Include all the personal notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);

            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

    }

}```
````

Comment: Maybe u can use push notifications. And in this method user don't have to open app. You sent mesaage to all user. I think this method  more useful for u.

Comment: Yes, but i would have to use firebase functions for that and i've never used them before.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your issue is on this line

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
```

According to the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
You should not be passing `"message"` to the database reference.

Comment: The application  keeps crashing as soon as I open it, even when i do not pass any string to getReference().

Comment: What is the Logcat output?

Comment: My best guess is you are passing a `HashMap` instead of a `String` to firebase. Check around line 40 of your `mainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 myRef.child("App").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = snapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child: children)
                {
                    String value = child.getValue(String.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the application crashes as soon as I launch it. Do you think the problem is with my implementation of child.getValue() method? Since I'm using String.class.

Comment: I realized what the problem was and just edited my answer. try it now. it should work fine.

Comment: It still keeps stopping/crashing whenever I launch the app. I also tried running the app without this addVlaueEventLsitener() function part, to see if there's anything else wrong with the app. But everything else runs fine without this part.

Comment: Share the crash report please. this way it's impossible to help

Comment: There is no crash report displayed. It just displays the home page and within a second the app closes. Here is a screenshot of the device when i launch the app a couple of times https://imgur.com/obB05rV.

Comment: this picture shows there is a crash. check the catlog before you click "close app"

Comment: https://imgur.com/qFHsOQN This is the logcat after I run the android app through android studio.